# Difference between simulate() and forecast() in "forecast" package

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am working on building a time series model.

However, I am having trouble understanding what the difference is between the `simulate` function and the `forecast` function in the `forecast` package.

Suppose I built an arima model and want to use it to simulate future values as long as 10 years. The data is hourly and we have a year worth of data.

When using `forecast` to predict the next 1000-step-ahead estimation, I got the following plot.

**Using forecast method**

[image]

Then I used the `simulate` function to simulate the next 1000 simulated values and got the following plot.

**Using simulate method**

[image]

Data points after the red line are simulated data points.

In the latter example, I used the following codes to simulate the future values.

```
simulate(arima1, nsim=1000, future=TRUE, bootstrap=TRUE))
```

where `arima1` is my trained arima model, bootstrap residuals are used because the model residuals are not very normal.

Per definition in the `forecast` package, `future=TRUE` means that we are simulating future values based on the historical data.

Can anyone tell me what the difference is between these two method? Why does `simulate()` give me a much more realistic results but forecasted values from `forecast()` just converge to a constant after several iterations (no much fluctuation to the results from `simulate()`)?

Answer (score 7):

A simulation is a possible future sample path of the series.

A point forecast is the mean of all possible future sample paths. So the point forecasts are usually much less variable than the data.

The `forecast` function produces point forecasts (the mean) and interval forecasts containing the estimated variation in the future sample paths.

As a side point, an ARIMA model is not appropriate for this time series because of the skewness. You might need to use a transformation first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Is there some documentation on how simulations are performed? Indeed, I would like to reproduce the `simulate` function to build prediction intervals (with your trick described [here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast-intervals-for-aggregates/)) but using python instead of R.